# How an Authentication Server works

Tags: authentication, networking, architecture

As the title suggests, I am not sure how an Authentication Server works. I have implemented authentication on multiple websites but it hasn't ever sat on a separate server. So, how would this architecture work? Is there material online that can explain this (I couldn't find any)? Advantages/ Disadvantages of this approach when compared to an implementing authentication on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

Having different authentication systems per application would land the user to create multiple profile which could be cumbersome for the user. Also architecturally you are creating tight coupling between application and authentication.

You should consider & design authentication as a simple Service/API call, this would help you in removing the coupling, achieving re-usability and maintainability. Following are few benefits of Authentication as a service or separate system:

1. Isolating Authentication system would create a path for implementing Single Sign On feature.
2. Implement changes and testing would be easier.
3. You can have the road-map to apply standardization in elegant manner.
4. In future your authentication can also handle authorization responsibilities.
5. When you change your Authentication system to a new IDAM solution, the impact on the business applications is reduced or eliminated.

You can find lot of Identity Access Management Solutions in the market which are pretty much industry standard. I would recommend you to research on SSO & IDAM products, which should give you comprehensive idea about the above mentioned points.

Comment: So If I was to write a web service that would only execute if a user is authenticated, would I only call an authentication api throughout my service and handle it accordingly? Have you seen material on the web that would illustrate the architecture? Great answer btw, that is what I was looking for

Comment: Yes you are correct. I also used on WSO2 IDAM solution and we used OAuth protocol to handshake with applications. You also have a token mechanism thru which you have maintain the session between the services. I would recommend you read this material. http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/